# How would you write the Date object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

The Date object might be a good illustration of how to create objects in JavaScript.
It has too many methods to make it a concise example, but I'd like to see how the framework of such an object might be constructed.

Let's pretend there is a bare-metal value called ClockTick or something like that, that returns the milliseconds.

So the Date object is used as both a getter:

```
function Date() {
   return ClockTick;
}
```

and a setter:

```
function Date(milliseconds) {
}
```

with overloading:

```
function Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) {
}
```

Q: Without being exhaustive, how would you write the Date object in JavaScript assuming there wasn't one built in already?

Comment: Javascript doesn't support overloading at the language level. You would have to do something like this - http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/.

Comment: Though it uses some native references, Google's V8 [still has a decent example with `DateConstructor`](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js#141).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the basic examples you gave, you basically want to check two things:

1. Is `Date` called as a constructor with `new`, or called directly.
2. How many arguments are passed.

I'd probably do something like this:

```
function Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds){
    if (!(this instanceof Date)){
        // If 'this' is not a Date, then the function was called without 'new'.
        return /* current date string */
    }
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        // Populate the object's date with current time
    } else if (arguments.length === 1){
        // Populate the object's date based on 'arguments[0]'
    } else {
        // Populate the object's date based on all of the arguments
    }
}
```

As far as representing the actual date values, it is really up to you. Only the external interface is defined, so you could store it as a timestamp, or separate values for day/month/year etc.

On the side of storing the values, you have a few options:

1. You could store the values on the `this` itself, and add all of the methods for `Date` onto `Date.prototype`. This method is potentially faster because the functions are all shared on the prototype so they do not get recreated, but it means that the values have to be stored on `this` which means they will be publically visible to people using your class.
2. You can store the values on a second object inside the date constructor, and then assign all of the `Date` functions onto `this` inside the constructor, capturing a reference to the date value object. This has the upside of hiding the internal values, but means that you need to recreate the functions for every new `Date` object that is creates.

e.g.

```
function Date(...){
   this.dayPrivate = day;
}

Date.prototype.getDay = function(){
   return this.dayPrivate;
};
```

vs

```
function Date(...){
    this.getDay = function(){
       return day;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth! When it comes to "Populate the object's date", that would require a closure, wouldn't it?  And if a closure, then some sort of a function within the function.

Comment: @Phillip: No, not an additional function - the constructor function is closure enough. And populating the `Date` object works with an internal value which hardly can be represented in plain JS - the nearest thing would be creating the constand `valueOf` method.